# Changed State based on the key

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management

I want to changed boolean state based on the value is passed

```
class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      formElement: {
        home: true,
        booth: false,
        summary: false
      },
    };
  }

  buttonClickHandler(event, nextView) {  //nextView == summary
    // nextView == summary then summary would be true and booth would be flase and home would flase too
  }
}

Here based on nextView all state value should be reserved.

Thanks in advance..!!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

considering you are receiving nextView as  home/booth/summary and based on this you want to set corresponding key i.e. formElement[nextView] = true and for other keys i.e. formElement[!nextView] = false.

You can try following:

```
buttonClickHandler (event, nextView) {  
  const { formElement } = this.state;
  Object.keys(formElement).forEach(key => {
     this.setState({
       formElement: {
         ...formElement,
         [key]: key === nextView  // here will check if the current key matches nextView
       }
     });
  });
}
```

By the way I feel you might use simpler state variable, if possible.
like

```
this.state = {
      formElement: 'home'
};
```

then

```
 buttonClickHandler (event, nextView) {  
      this.setState({
        formElement: nextView
      });
   }
```

It is just a thought for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle.

Comment: const { formElement } = this.state; This statement has giving like this : Must use destructuring state assignment